# Scrapy - crawling archives of website plus all subdirectories

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

So I'm trying to scrape data from archived versions of a website using Scrapy. Here is my code:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import *
from scrapy.item import *
from scrapy.linkextractors import *
from scrapy.loader import *
from scrapy.spiders import *
from scrapy.utils.log import *
from scrapy.utils.project import *

try:
    from urllib.parse import urlparse
except ImportError:
    from urlparse import urlparse
    
class VSItem(Item):
    value = Field()

class vsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "lever"
    start_urls = [
        "https://web.archive.org/web/20051120125133/http://www.novi.k12.mi.us/default.aspx"
    ]
    rules = (
            Rule(
                LinkExtractor(allow="https:\/\/web.archive.org\/web\/\d{14}\/http:\/\/www.novi.k12.mi.us\/.*"),
                callback="parse"
                ),
            )

    def parse(self, response):
        for elem in response.xpath("/html"):
            it = VSItem()
            it["value"] = elem.css("input[name='__VIEWSTATE']").extract()
            yield it
 
process = CrawlerProcess(get_project_settings())

process.crawl(vsSpider)
process.start() # the script will block here until the crawling is finished
```

I set the `start_urls` to `https://web.archive.org/web/20051120125133/http://www.novi.k12.mi.us/`since that is the earliest archived version of the page.

This script extracts the element I want from the page listed, but then stops here.

My question is: How can I automatically crawl every single archive of both the homepage (/default.aspx) and every sub-directory of the main site (e.g. not just /default.aspx but also, for example, /Schools/noviHigh/default.aspx and everything else)? (Basically loop through every possible URL that matches `/https:\/\/web.archive.org\/web\/.\d{14}/http:\/\/www.novi.k12.mi.us\/.*/g`, the `\d{14}` is because the date stamp is in the form `YYYYMMDDHHmmSS`)

Answer (score 0):

Try this on for size!! With this, the spider should now crawl every archived version of the homepage and every sub-directory of the main site :)

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from scrapy.item import Item, Field
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings

class VSItem(Item):
    value = Field()

class vsSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "lever"
    start_urls = [
"https://web.archive.org/web/20051120125133/http://
 www.novi.k12.mi.us/default.aspx"
   ]
rules = (
    Rule(
        LinkExtractor(allow=r"https:\/\/web\.archive\.org\/web\/\d{14}\/http:\/\/www\.novi\.k12\.mi\.us\/.*"),
        callback="parse_item",
        follow=True
    ),
)

def parse_item(self, response):
    for elem in response.xpath("/html"):
        it = VSItem()
        it["value"] = elem.css("input[name='__VIEWSTATE']").extract_first()
        yield it

process = CrawlerProcess(get_project_settings())
process.crawl(vsSpider)
process.start()
```

Best of luck!